# How to draw specific time intervals of rows from a data frame?

Tags: r, function, matrix, return, extract

I have a data frame with 3523 observation and 92 variables.

Below an example of a data frame with 10 observations and 04:00-05:00

```
     04:00 04:15 04:30 05:00 05:15 05:30
 1:     -     -     -     -     -     -
 2:     2     2     2     -     2     2
 3:     2     -     -     2     2     2
 4:     -     -     2     -     2     2
 5:     -     -     -     -     2     2
 6:     2     -     2     2     -     2
 7:     -     -     -     -     2     2
 8:     2     2     -     2     2     2
 9:     -     -     -     -     2     2
10:     2     2     -     2     2     2

.
```

The columns define 24h time from 4:00am till 4:00am (15 minutes interval). The rows define number of observation.

Each row contain values '-' and '2'.

I want to extract the beginning and the ending of the intervals starting with '2'

For example 2: 04:00-04:30; 3: 04:00 ; 05:00 4: 04:30

I also would like to save the output in an excel or txt file. Could you help me please

Comment: That's not clear, how you calculate `n`. The interval starts with `2` and ends with `2` no mater if there are `-` inbetween? Row number corresponds to `n` (e.g. row 2 - `n == 2`)? If so, why `2: 04:15 -  04:30`? Shouldn't it be `2: 04:00 - 04:30`?

Comment: Dear @utubun yes, you are true - I corrected the mistake - > could you help me please?

Comment: I'll try to do my best, @Mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited it after after the discussion with @Mate (see the comments to this answer):

### Solution:

```
library(tidyverse) 

dat %>%
  rownames_to_column("n") %>%
  mutate(n = as.integer(n)) %>%
  gather(key = "time", value = "observation", -n) %>% 
  group_by(n) %>%
  filter(observation == "2") %>%
  summarize(
    interval = paste(time[seq(1, n(), 2)], 
                     c(time, "...")[seq(2, n() + n() %% 2, 2)], 
                     sep = "-",
                     collapse = ", ")
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  write_csv("my_results.csv")
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
       n interval                                                                    
   <int> <chr>                                                                       
 1     1 04:30-14:00, 19:30-20:15, 22:30-01:15, 03:45-...                            
 2     2 06:15-08:00, 09:00-12:00, 13:45-16:30, 18:45-23:15, 00:30-02:15             
 3     3 06:00-06:30, 08:00-09:45, 11:15-13:30, 14:15-23:15, 01:00-01:30             
 4     4 20:00-21:15, 23:30-03:15                                                    
 5     5 05:00-09:30, 10:00-10:30, 11:45-12:00, 13:15-13:30, 14:00-20:15, 20:30-21:3~
 6     6 07:45-08:30, 09:15-13:15, 19:15-19:30, 20:30-20:45, 21:00-21:45, 01:45-...  
 7     7 09:30-17:45, 21:15-...                                                      
 8     8 07:00-09:30, 12:45-18:00, 19:00-21:15, 00:15-02:00                          
 9     9 05:45-06:15, 09:00-16:00, 17:15-19:45, 21:15-22:30, 23:00-...               
10    10 10:00-10:15, 12:15-13:30, 16:15-16:45, 21:30-23:45, 00:45-01:30
```

### Data

```
colnms <- paste(
  str_pad(rep(c(4:23, 0:3), each = 4), 2, "left", 0),
  str_pad(rep(c(0, 15, 30, 45), times = 24), 2, "left", 0),
  sep = ":"
)

set.seed(53248604)
dat <- matrix(sample(c("-", 2), 9600, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = T), nrow = 100)

dimnames(dat) <- list(1:100, colnms)

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

Comment: Dear @utubun you are amazing is working; but I have a big request to you how to mine the interval that starts and ends with 2. As example example 3 it would be 04:00 and 05:00? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean not to count the intervals where `n('2') == 1` as done by @jay.sf?  btw look at @jay.sf answer, we both can learn a lot from it.

Comment: Dear @utubun what I mean to count the intervals not just the first and the last '2'; but also the 'spaces' or the intervals that make the case  between then. For example let's assume that the table has "2" from 07:15 till 10:30 then there is a "-" at 11:00 there is another interval with "2" till 11:45 than there is "-" and at 12:30 start another "2" intervals till 14:45 This I am failing to understand how to code..Could you help me please?

Comment: Ok, let me think about it

Comment: If I understand it right, there are going to be intervals `07:15-10:30`, `11:00-11:45`, `12:30-14:45` etc. Do you want it as a one string, i.e: `07:15-10:30, 11:00-11:45, 12:30-14:45` or as a separate rows for each interval for given `n`?

Comment: Dear utubun I aim for one string - thank you for your kindness

Comment: Still holds that if I found intervals `07:15-10:30, 11:00-11:45, 12:30-14:45`, after that there are `n` `'-'`s and somewhere after that, let's say at `22:45` there is `2` but not `2`s afterwards, just `'-'`s till the end of the table, I return only `07:15-10:30, 11:00-11:45, 12:30-14:45` and ignore `22:45`?

Comment: Apologize for this late reply; true you need to return all the 2; so 07:15-10:30, 11:00-11:45, 12:30-14:45 and 22:45-thank you and apologize

Comment: Hey, @MátéJánosLõrincz have a look, is it what you need?

Comment: Dear utubun no words to thank you -> what this does it returns all the '2' which is good; nut is it possible to receive the beginning and the end time of the '2's not all time points; otherwise is great!!! thank you

Comment: It's not clear to me, what do you mean by "not all time points"... Code above returns for each row (providing there a at least 1 '2' - and I added the edit deleting the line filter(`n() > 1`) the time interval of two adjacent '2's (or just one time point, if it is not preceded or followed by '2'). That is, as mentioned, done for each row separately. Please @MátéJánosLõrincz, could you explain me what am I missing?

Comment: @MátéJánosLõrincz do you need to find the intervals for whole table, merging all the rows together?

Comment: Dear @utubun I aim for output based on your example eg 2: 04:00-04:30; 05:15-05:30 3: 04:00; 05:00-05:30; 4: 04:40; 05:15-05:30, etc. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `range()` like so:

```
fun <- function(dat) {
  L <- lapply(seq_along(dat), function(x, ...) {
    if (length(dat[x, dat[x, ] == 2, ]) >= 2) {
      range(names(dat[x, dat[x, ] == 2]))
    } else if (length(dat[x, dat[x, ] == 2, ]) == 1) {
      c(names(dat)[which(dat[x, ] == 2)], NA)
    }})
  setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, L)), c("t0", "t1"))
}
```

***Yields***

```
> fun(df1)
     t0    t1
1 04:00 04:30
2 04:00 04:45
3 04:30  <NA>
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(rep("-", 4), rep(2, 3), "-", 
                                    rep(c(2, rep("-", 2)), 2),2, rep("-", 25)), 
                                  ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)),
                strftime(as.POSIXct((0:3)*15*60 + 3*60*60, origin=Sys.Date() ), 
                         format="%H:%M"))

> df1
   04:00 04:15 04:30 04:45
1      -     -     -     -
2      2     2     2     -
3      2     -     -     2
4      -     -     2     -
5      -     -     -     -
6      -     -     -     -
7      -     -     -     -
8      -     -     -     -
9      -     -     -     -
10     -     -     -     -
```

Comment: Cool answer, made my mental notes about your approach.